# Change color of div by id in javascript function after reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm printing data from mysql in divs using bootstrap as well with a foreach loop. Each div has a button "Ordered" which should change some data in the db and also change the background color of the specific div. I use an onclick function which sends the div's id to the url and reloads the page. When I tried changing the color of the div with the bootstrap class inside the function it just flickers for a moment and reloads the page with the previous color.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    if(params.get("num")) {
        <?php 
     $id = $_GET['num'];
     $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=...', '...', '...',[
     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]);
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE orders SET status = 1 WHERE id = ?');
     $stmt->execute([$id]);
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
     ?>
        document.getElementById(num).style.backgroundColor = '#fcf3d4';

        alert("after the page gets reloaded");
    }
  });

  function change(num) {
    var number = num;
    alert("before page gets reloaded");
    window.location.href = "http://ecohfood.com/login_success.php?num=" + number;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-6" id="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>">
  <div id="bottom">
    <button type="button" id="b<?php echo $v['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-success" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $v['id']; ?>').style.backgroundColor = '#fcf3d4';
      change(<?php echo $v['id']; ?>);">Ordered</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="del(<?php echo $v['id']; ?>)">Delete</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: "//connect with db and update information" - this isn't really shown here - but one thing to note is that it comes after the page is refreshed. Everything after `window.location.href = ` will be ignored.

Comment: when the page reloads, the js, css and html load again. That's why you see the flicker. The onClick event tries to fire, so it changes the style slightly but then the page reloads and everything is reset to its initial value, because along with the newly loaded html, the js and css load anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, you can't do what you're trying to, in the way you're trying to.

Once you reload / change the page, the context you're running in is done.  Everything after "window.location.href = ..." won't be executed - you've moved on to a new page.  You can't affect that future page from the one that you've navigated away from.

What you can do, is, when that page loads, change the color.  Attach an event to the page's load event, check for the `num` variable you just passed to the page, and if it's set how you want it, then you can change the color / connect with the db / whatever.

So the new function would look something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  // This will run every time the page loads, so let's check to make 
  // sure the variable is set.  Only if it has been set and the page 
  // has been reloaded, do we want to execute this color-change code

  // Get the parameters from the URL
  let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  // Check that the one we want is truthy
  if(params.get("num")) {
      //connect with db and update information
      document.getElementById(num).style.backgroundColor = '#fcf3d4';

      alert("after the page gets reloaded");
  }
});

function change(num) {
  var number = num;
  alert("before page gets reloaded");
  window.location.href = "http://ecohfood.com/login_success.php?num=" + number;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! I inserted that into the code and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make the db update before the window.location.href = "http://ecohfood.com/login_success.php?num=" + number;

And when the update is succes add a new Param in the Url, something like

window.location.href = "http://ecohfood.com/login_success.php?num=" + number&update = success;

and add this to the js file of this page http://ecohfood.com/login_success.php

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var aux = urlParam(update);
  if (aux!= ''){
    $("#id").css("Backgroud","#fffff")
  }

});

function urlParam(name){
 var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
 if (results==null){
  return null;
 }
 else{
  return results[1] || 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't make the db update before the window.location.href = "http://ecohfood.com/login_success.php?num=" + number; because I get the id from the url after the reload